# Coding to make a SQL table from an InfoPath 2003 form without knowing the fields in advance

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, parsing, infopath

**Using:** InfoPath 2003 (and its XML), Microsoft SQL Server 2005, Visual Studio 2005, C# (to make a web service)

I've been trying to find something that does this already, and either my Google skills are failing or it's not actually possible, because I can't believe this hasn't already been needed by someone.

I am attempting to make a web service that takes an InfoPath form, gets the list of all the fields from the form (and their associated expected data types if the user bothered with validation), and creates a table in a SQL database with the same fields and expected types (probably using varchar as a default type where validation wasn't used).  I can't just list the fields ahead of time, because in theory, managers and engineers will be making new forms for all sorts of purposes and I need to avoid confusing them or giving them direct access to the server.

I've never done anything of this sort before, nor have I used XML (or C#, for that matter).  Before I drive myself crazy trying to make everything work, I need to know: is this possible?  I know XML documents are basically made of user-defined tags, and I don't know if there's any way to distinguish form fields from any other tags associated with rendering the document properly.  I also don't know if there are methods available for getting the expected data types.  If this stuff is possible, any guidance in how would be appreciated.

---

**Update**

Judging from an InfoPath form at the XML level, it seems that all of the fields are contained in the `<my:myFields>` tag.  It also contains the `<xd:SchemaInfo>` tag, so now I've got to figure out how to access all of the fields while ignoring that one.

I still don't know if I'm trying to do something that's weird, impossible for another reason, or bad practice, so advice from people who know things is always welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is totally possible. The only thing you need to make sure is, that the managers/engineers submit their form against your web service as string like shown in this screenshot.

[image]

The Reason why you need to submit the form as string is simple - you cannot configure IP to send XmlDocument object's directly. It is possible, however you need custom code in each form you/your cowokers create, so i'd suggest using the no-code solution.

Heres how you could implement the web service method.

```
[WebMethod]
public void CreateTable(string infoPathData)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(infoPathData);

    //gets the namespace uri - it is unique for each form
    string nsUri = doc.ChildNodes[3].Attributes["xmlns:my"].Value;

    var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsManager.AddNamespace("my", nsUri);

    //select the myField node
    var root = doc.SelectSingleNode("my:myFields", nsManager);

    var sqlStatement = new StringBuilder();
    sqlStatement.Append("CREATE TABLE ....");

    foreach (XmlNode n in root.ChildNodes)
    {
        //n.Name - gets the name of the node (incl. NS)
        //n.InnerText - gets the field value 

        //append to sqlStatement
    }

    //execute sql statement ...
}
```

You build an XmlDocument from the submitted IP data and then iterate it's fields. Depending on your requirements, you might also need to iterate child-nodes (i.e. if the form includes folders/repeating tables etc.) but thats really up to you ;-)

If you never worked with XmlDocument's before, be sure to check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

You will need to enforce some specific rules to people who use your web service like what happens when someone renames "my:myFields" to "my:myBlaBla" (which is possible) and submits his/her form to your web service. Also i suggest very heavy error-logging, because things can (and will!) go wrong with such a generic approach.

The only problem which i can think of is how to determine the data-type of each field because it is not included in the InfoPath form data. You could try the usual C# Conversion methods (like Int32.TryParse etc).

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: That was very helpful indeed!  I'll have to give this a try.

Comment: Note that i tried this using IP2010 but it shouldn't really matter... also, if you need any further help feel free to contact me, this sounds like an very interesting project :-)